# Why do images uploaded to Heroku disappear after one day?

Tags: heroku

I created a [React App](https://places-project-293209.web.app/) and its backend is hosted in Heroku. I can add images but after one day, those images are gone! I paid 7 dollars which is the hobby dyno. Should the images be stored in another service, or should I pay more money in Heroku?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Picture disappeared on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210486/picture-disappeared-on-heroku)

Comment: yes it does, thanks