# How to display image and files from heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

Hey guys I have this new site am working on and it has to do with uploading of files from the frontend to the backend folder and displaying the image through an api, using node js and express uploader when I ran it locally on my PC it worked perfectly, when I deployed it to heroku it worked and displayed the image but after a while it would show a broken link and it won't display anymore. Please I need help fixing it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do uploaded pictures disappear on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210486/why-do-uploaded-pictures-disappear-on-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Heroku does not save changes you make to the filesystem. To make this work, you need to use an external method of saving images, like aws of firebase.